# File.open returns integer not File inconsistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-io, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> ```
> temp_image = File.open(Rails.root.join("tmp","project_image.png"), 'wb') do |f| 
>   f.write(Base64.decode64(image_data))
> end
>
> puts temp_image
> puts File.open(Rails.root.join("tmp","project_image.png"))
> ```

Output:

> 24018
>
> ## < File:0x007fddd55c8db0 >

I want the first line to to return the file object as well.  Why is it returning the integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `x = File.open(...) do |f| ...` sets `x` to the result of the do block, not to the returned file (which is closed after the block finishes). So what you are effectively doing is setting `temp_image` to the result of `f.write`, which is the number of bytes written, not the file object.

Comment: if I add f to the next line after file.write in the block then I get IOError (closed stream): is there a way to return the file from the statement or not having to call File.open again?

Comment: Don't use File.open(...) with a block. Using it with a block will automatically close the file at the end of the block.